# BASH - using variable with string inside bash sed string (2 double quotes)

Tags: bash, sed

For some reasons this command is working in my telnet:

```
[ -n "$server" ] && busybox sed -i "2s/.*/$(cat /web/data/servers/usa.txt | busybox sed -n "${server}p")/" /web/data/settings.txt
```

But when i run in cgi bash script, it's not giving me the right output. I'm sure the problem is this but I don't know how to fix it:

```
$(cat /web/data/servers/usa.txt | busybox sed -n "${server}p")
```

Because there's another string(double quote) inside which conflicts in the outside. Pls help, I'm new in this.

Edited: example: **$server=7** which will get the string in line 7 at `/web/data/servers/usa.txt` which is **USA 7**, then will replace the string in line 2 of `/web/data/settings.txt`.
In my telnet, it outputs my desired value, but when I run it in cgi script it doesn't. I'm using the exact same code in both. I also have a code which is same but has no `$(...)` and it outputs the correct value I want.

Comment: What is the output you get, and what is the expected output?

Comment: example: **$server=7** which will get the string in line 7 at `/web/data/servers/usa.txt` which **USA 7**, then will replace the string in line 2 of `/web/data/settings.txt`
In my telnet, outputs my desired value, but when I run it in cgi script it doesn't. I'm using the exact same code in both. I also have a code which is not in my post, It is same as above but has no `$(...)` and it outputs the correct value I want.

Comment: You should really only need to use `busybox sed -n "${server}p" < /web/data/servers/usa.txt` or even without the `<` depending on which command you are using (in your example 1 or 2).

Comment: I just need to get a specific string of another file while inside the sed string. may I know if it's possible? thanks

Comment: Sure it's possible, but you haven't said what the error or issue is; it's unclear what you mean by "when I run it in cgi script".

Comment: I think I got the problem now. When I initialize a declare in a file with new lines, I can't seem to use it in **sed** like this: `echo "\n\n" > newfile.txt` then I will use `busybox sed -n "2p" newfile.txt`. it will not print any because it seem to be reading the declared string in one line. The weird thing is it's not happening in telnet, only in cgi bash script. I still don't know how to fix that so I will just overwrite the previous strings in the lines.

Comment: I mean is `busybox sed -i "2s/.*/new/" newfile.txt`, it will not add anything because the file still only has 1 line after declaring `echo "\n\n" > newfile.txt`.

Comment: Use `printf`not `echo`. Motivation: https://superuser.com/a/256498